# Baffled by } jquery error

Tags: javascript, jquery, live

so I keep getting the error:

> employeesScript.js:3Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {.

It is driving me nuts because I can't figure out what is causing it.  I also ran it through JSFiddle and got the following error:

```
Error:
Problem at line 3 character 50: Expected ')' and instead saw '{'.
$(".employeesPostHours").live("click", fuction() {

Problem at line 3 character 51: Missing semicolon.
$(".employeesPostHours").live("click", fuction() {

Problem at line 45 character 1: Expected '(end)' and instead saw '}'.
});

Implied global: $ 1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,20, fuction 3, employeeEntry 5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13, employeesId 6,23, employeesEmail 7,24, employeesStartTime 8,25, employeesEndTime 9,26, employeesDate 10,27, employeesExtraMoney 11,28, employeesExtraMoneyDetail 12,29, driving 13,30, onTruck 14,31, warehouse 15,32, phones 16,33, flyering 17,34, wageChange 18,35, alert 38
```

Here is my Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".employeesPostHours").live("click", fuction() {
$("#employeesSection1Form").append("Please Wait...");
employeeEntry = $(this).closest("div");
employeesId = $(employeeEntry).find("#employeesId").val();
employeesEmail = $(employeeEntry).find("#employeesEmail").val();
employeesStartTime = $(employeeEntry).find("#employeesStartTime").val();
employeesEndTime = $(employeeEntry).find("#employeesEndTime").val();
employeesDate = $(employeeEntry).find("#employeesDate").val();
employeesExtraMoney = $(employeeEntry).find("#employeesExtraMoney").val();
employeesExtraMoneyDetail = $(employeeEntry).find("#employeesExtraMoneyDetail").val();
driving = $(employeeEntry).find("#driving").val();
onTruck = $(onTruck).find("#onTruck").val();
warehouse = $(warehouse).find("#warehouse").val();
phones = $(phones).find("#phones").val();
flyering = $(flyering).find("#flyering").val();
wageChange = $(wageChange).find("#wageChange").val();

$.post(
            'employeesHoursPost.php', 
            {
                'employeesId': employeesId,
                'employeesEmail': employeesEmail,
                'employeesStartTime': employeesStartTime,
                'employeesEndTime': employeesEndTime,
                'employeesDate': employeesDate,
                'employeesExtraMoney': employeesExtraMoney,
                'employeesExtraMoneyDetail': employeesExtraMoneyDetail,
                'driving': driving,
                'onTruck': onTruck,
                'warehouse': warehouse,
                'phones': phones,
                'flyering': flyering,
                'wageChange': wageChange
            },
            function (response) {
            alert (response);
            }
);
return false;
});

});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`fuction` is misspelled. It should be `function` on line 3.

Comment: I can't believe how long I spent looking at that.  Works perfectly now, thanks so much...ill mark the answer as soon as it lets me

Comment: Happens to the best of us. :)

Comment: Use a syntax-checking editor to write your code, and you'll spot problems like this as you type them, rather than when you run it. (Netbeans is my choice, but there are many others)